# how to make a group of radiobutton so that you can only select one?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, mobile, mobile-development

how to make a group of radiobutton so that you can only select one?

i wanted to make only one radiobutton that is selectable

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Add your radio buttons in a RadioGroup as below.

```
<RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
          ....
        > 
       <RadioButton   
           android:id="@+id/radiobutton1
           .../>
       ...
    </RadioGroup>
```

Comment: i'm a bigger i'm having trouble coding this, can I do it from the design tab?

Comment: What do you mean? Please describe more about your code. Are you using compose or xml views? Do you want to do this programmatically?